# Spring boot application is running on EC2, isn't responding to the public dns of the EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I have a spring boot application, deployed in the EC2 instance. when I hit the DNS it says the site can not be reached.

spring boot application in the ec2, running successfully

[image]

hitting the public DNS with the port number

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to open the port in the security group

Comment: what port are you using? 8080?

Comment: Yes, I didn't open the port. Now it's working. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to [Authorize inbound traffic for your Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Comment: I didn't notice it, opened the port, and it worked.
Thank you

Comment: can you please put it as solved